# Difference on Keras 1.2.2 and Keras 2.2 Predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I tried to predict a sine curve with a LSTM neural Network. I tried some time but i couldn't really get a good result for predicting predictions. After some values the sine curve always got chaotic. So I got some inspiration from this article:

http://www.jakob-aungiers.com/articles/a/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction

His sine curve has just a little shift even when predicting on previous Predictions. So i copied his exact code but got this prediction:
[image]

Instead of his:
[image]

After some time I realized that he used:

```
TensorFlow 1.0
Keras 1.2.2
```

So I installed Keras 1.2.2 to see if it makes a difference and tensorflow version 1.2.0 because earlier versions arent available on windows. Then I got this prediction:
[image]

You can see that sine curve is more accurate because it is in its value range of [-1,1] but is way more shifted than his prediction.

I have tried this multiple times with very similar results. Keras 2.2 Prediction Amplitude always gets smaller after some time while Keras 1.2 stays in its value range. But I never get as of a good prediction like his.

Do I need more training? I have used 20 epochs and a batch size of 512.
How do I get such a prediction?
And do newer Keras Version give more cautious predictions?

This is the model I used:

```
def build_model(layers):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_shape=(None, layers[0]),
        #units=layers[1],
        output_dim=layers[1],
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print("> Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

With these parameters:

```
model = build_model([1, 50, 100, 1])
```

The whole code can be found here

https://github.com/VictorW96/sinprediction

Comment: You should make your code fully reproducible by adding your data generation routines

Comment: There may be differences in how "dropout" is applied in different versions. And there may also be differences in how the LSTMCell is implemented. Also, there may be a lot of differences between the initial weights, the lerning rates, decays, etc....

Comment: I agree with @desertnaut, I'd be happy to investigate this if I have all the code!

Comment: @desertnaut and mpariente I have updated the post with the full code